# Using arrays in loops

Tags: php, arrays

I've tried to use an array in a loop (in PHP) so that I can display 5 random values. But the problem is that the program doesn't work and nothing appears on the browser.

What's wrong with this code? Have I missed something?

```
<?php

$my_array = array('Mohammed', 'Khaled', 'Nasser', 'Yasser', 'Ahmed', 'Badr', 'Ibrahim', 'Ali', 'Turkey', 'Abdullah', 'Bandar', 'Omar', 'Saleh', 'Saeed', 'Salem');
$random_array = array_rand($my_array, 5);

for ($x==0 ; $x==4 ; $x++) {
    echo $my_array[$random_array[$x]] . "</br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: $x == 0 is a comparison, you want an assignment $x = 0, the loop condition should be a comparison $x < 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `for` loop as

```
for ($x=0 ; $x<=4 ; $x++) {
    echo $my_array[$random_array[$x]] . "</br>";
}
```

You need to learn how `for` loop works

```
1. $x=0;//Initializing value of $x 
 2. $x<=4;//Loop till the value of $x is less than or equal to 4 
 3. $x++;//Increment the value of $x by one i.e. $x= $x+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it more simple. Also `==` is for comparison not assignment.

```
foreach(array_rand($my_array, 5) as $item) {
    echo $item . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work 

<?php

$my_array = array('Mohammed', 'Khaled', 'Nasser', 'Yasser', 'Ahmed', 'Badr',   'Ibrahim', 'Ali', 'Turkey', 'Abdullah', 'Bandar', 'Omar', 'Saleh', 'Saeed', 'Salem');
$random_array = array_rand($my_array, 5);

for ($x=0 ; $x<6 ; $x++) {
echo $my_array[$random_array[$x]] . "</br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: `$x < 6` should be `$x < 5`